# Connecting Ecobee to Lechivar dual zone system

Tags: wiring

Have a dual zone Lochinvar system. Trying to hook up two ecobees for each zone. I ran a new C wire as we did not require it before.
Everything seems to be connected properly but the ecobees don’t start the connection process and they stay in the initial ‘hi’ mode where the thermostat acclimates to the zones. I feel I’m missing something in the wiring into the valve switches or something else.
[image: transformer wires are reversed (white is Rc, red is W/E or W/Aux)]

Comment: What model is your boiler, and can you post its wiring diagram or installation manual please?

Comment: Lechinvar Knight.  I received a message from Ecobee that maybe I have insufficient voltage but I had the HVAC company run the C wire (converted gorund to 24v C wire)...not sure if that is truly the issue.

Comment: https://www.lochinvar.com/products/residential-boilers/knight-fire-tube-boiler/

Comment: It's the wall mount boiler.  I believe SKU: WHB110N - Looks like a 2017 or newer version.

Comment: https://www.markssupply.ca/ASSETS/DOCUMENTS/ITEMS/EN/Lochinvar_100285818_Manual.pdf

Comment: Posted by another person: I connected my ecobee to my Lochinvar boiler by connecting the R & W terminals to the thermostat terminals on the boiler.  For the C wire, I cut both the blue and yellow 24V wires from the 24V transformer in the middle of the boiler.  Using my voltmeter, I tested each to ground.  One read 24V, the other read 0V.  The 0V wire is your common wire, and you can splice the C-wire to the ecobee there.  beware that if a safety trips in the boiler, it will likely kill power to the ecobee because it will interrupt the current to the R terminal on the boiler's control board.

Comment: "Trying to hook up two ecobees for each zone." I presume this is a typo and it should read, "Trying to hook up two ecobees, _one_ for each zone." Otherwise, you'll have to explain how you want 2 thermostats to control a single zone.